# How Do I Properly Setup For Cross Domain Script Execution?

Tags: javascript, iframe, http-headers

We utilize a third party reporting application server. Our application (we will call this Site A) includes a script, provided by the reporting server, that has a method for embedding reports. When the method is called, it creates an iFrame that loads the requested report, scripts and styles from the reporting server (we will call this Site B).

The report page loads as expected, embedded in it's iFrame. Interaction, within the report, runs as expected. However, the report page (from Site B) then sends a postMessage() to the parent (Site A) to call a method to resize the container element holding the iFrame, and another postMessage() to the parent (Site A) to scroll to the top of same container element.

The vendor tells us we need to implement the proper CORS settings to allow this to work, offering no further explanation other than "other clients are using this approach". Currently it throws an error in the console stating:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "[Site B]" from
>   accessing a cross-origin frame.

I've read a ton of documentation, on MDN and other sites, over the past two days and I am still confused as to which server which settings are applied towards? I have seen several examples regarding setting headers here and there, but nearly everything I've read applies solely to making Ajax requests from the client (served by Site A) to the remote (Site B), and nothing at all regarding what is necessary for the scenario we are dealing with. Anyone out there that can shed some light here? Which server needs which headers?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS is irrelevant here.

The error message indicates that Site B is trying to access something on Site A which is forbidden. That means that Site B *should* be using `postMessage`, but isn't (or at least, isn't correctly).

Comment: @ayxos answer is also technically correct, though we already had this in place (just needed to verify I was doing that right). Further review, after reading Quentin's answer, showed that the reporting server's scripts were incorrect. The vender already has a fix, we just haven't applied the upgrade yet. Thanks to all who answered.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid CORS problems you need the following: 
if site A is using an iframe to load site B. On site B NGINX/APACHE configuration you need to include this headers:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
```

on APACHE: https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

on NGINX: https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html